# Moments about the mean of a uniform distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, expectation, uniform-distribution

I really don't know what needs to be completed here, because I don't understand the parameters of alpha and beta:

> Show that if a random variable has a uniform density with the parameters alpha and beta, the $r$th moment about the mean is $\frac{1}{r+1}\left(\frac{\beta-\alpha}{2}\right)^r$ and zero otherwise.

Comment: I think you supposed to assume the  random variable is uniformly distributed on the interval $[\alpha,\beta],$ which is to say its density function $f$ is given by $f(x)=1/(\beta-\alpha)$ when $x\in[\alpha,\beta]$ and $0$ otherwise.

Comment: I edited your formula, as it should actually be, with the parameters having the meaning commented above. Check if it is ok.

Comment: You have the distribution $\mathsf{Unif}(\alpha,\beta).$ That is, $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are the endpoints of the support. Perhaps see [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_(continuous)#Generating_functions). You may need to use  L'Hopital's rule.

Answer (score 1):

$\alpha$ is the lower end of the uniform distribution while $\beta$ is the upper end.  All possible values between them are equally likely

Hint:

$$E[X]=\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2}$$

since the mean is also the mid point, so you want to calculate

$$E\left[\left(X-E[X]\right)^r\right]=\dfrac1{\beta-\alpha}\int_\alpha^\beta \left(x-\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2}\right)^r \, dx$$

Comment: You forgot to divide by $\beta-\alpha$, to make the total probability $1.$

Comment: @kimchilover Thank you - edited